# Fixed side chat menu using flex box

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I will do my best to showcase my problem in hopes of finding a solution. I am creating an angular app. I have a component that is called chat.

It is inside a html body that has 100% height. Here is the code

```css
.main-container-chat {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
}

.message-box-container {
  border: 1px solid red;
  overflow: scroll;
}

.message-box {
  text-align: left;
  padding-left: 5px;
  font-size: 13px;
}

.chat-container {
  height: 100%;
  width: 270px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: fixed;
  background-color: yellow;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.chat-sub-container {
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div _ngcontent-c0="" class="chat-container">
  <div _ngcontent-c0="" class="chat-sub-container">
    <app-chat _ngcontent-c0="" _nghost-c1="">
      <div _ngcontent-c1="" class="main-container-chat">
        <div _ngcontent-c1="" class="message-box-container" id="message-box-container">
        </div>
        <div _ngcontent-c1="" class="chat-input"><input _ngcontent-c1="" class="ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid">
          <button _ngcontent-c1="">Send</button>
        </div>
        <div _ngcontent-c1="" class="chat-detail">
          <p _ngcontent-c1="">User count: 1</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </app-chat>
  </div>
</div>
```

I know how CSS and HTML can get a bit messy. But I hope this is readable.

Notes:
- Using position:fixed, I am able to keep the chat component fixed on the left side. When I scrolling down the chat bar stays in the correct position. 
- The main problem is when setting **message-box-container** the send button and user count div disappears. I just want the the whole chat bar to stay at 100% height no matter the browser height.

I just want the whole chat bar to stay at 100% height no matter the browser height.

This is what I currently have...

[current chat style](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8bX99.png)

and this what I'm looking to accomplish.

[chat style desired](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LJWQb.png)

Notice in second image the area for input and send button are at the bottom. Ideally when the user decreases the browser height, this should stay the same. The only thing that changes is window for chat messages.

I'm trying to emulate what Twitch is doing on with their chat. I am using Flex Containers.

EDIT:

If I add to message-box-container flex:1 or flex-grow:1: This happens to my chat box:

[flex1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R0tWX.png)

EDIT::::
Just in case, here is a better full scope of the whole website. Again this is angular. The chat box is its' own component.

[fullscreenofexample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LtXiR.png)

EDIT---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

If you check the last photo in my question. You'll notice there is additional content above the chat box. Changing the .chat-container to 82% fixed the problem where adding Flex:1 to message-box-container caused the input box to disappear. Changing the height percentage fixed this.

**But now the problem is the chat box dynamically expands, but it doesn't shrink when minimizing the screen**

Comment: Twitch doesn't use fixed positioning for the chat box. Could that be what's ruining everything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to modify your layout but is this what you are looking for? http://jsfiddle.net/9mn1aueL/2/

```css
.main-container-chat {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
}

.message-box-container {
  border: 1px solid red;
  /* overflow: scroll; */
  flex: 1 0 auto;
}

.message-box {
  text-align: left;
  padding-left: 5px;
  font-size: 13px;
}

.chat-container {
  height: 100%;
  width: 270px;
  position: fixed;
  background-color: yellow;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="chat-container">
  <app-chat>
    <div class="main-container-chat">
      <div class="message-box-container" id="message-box-container">
      </div>
      <div class="chat-input">
        <input class="ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid">
        <button>Send</button>
      </div>
      <div class="chat-detail">
        <p>User count: 1</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </app-chat>
</div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work for me. But yes, that is what I'm trying to do on my website.

Comment: So, you want your layout to be intact? Is that why this solution won't work for you?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by intact sorry.

Comment: I was wondering if you are not open to changes in the layout? Or is there some other reason you think this solution is not working for you?

Comment: Potentially I am. But I'd like to stick with flexboxs. I just posted an image of the current layout

Comment: I got your solution workng. Thank you very much for helping me out. Learned a lot about the forest of CSS and Flexboxs.

Comment: @Nov Awesome! Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to set [`flex-grow: 1`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-grow) on `.message-box-container`, allowing it to expand to fill the available space. Also note that you'll probably also want to remove `overflow: scroll` to better match your design.

```css
.main-container-chat {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
}

.message-box-container {
  border: 1px solid red;
  /* overflow: scroll; */
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.message-box {
  text-align: left;
  padding-left: 5px;
  font-size: 13px;
}

.chat-container {
  height: 100%;
  width: 270px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: fixed;
  background-color: yellow;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.chat-sub-container {
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div _ngcontent-c0="" class="chat-container">
  <div _ngcontent-c0="" class="chat-sub-container">
    <app-chat _ngcontent-c0="" _nghost-c1="">
      <div _ngcontent-c1="" class="main-container-chat">
        <div _ngcontent-c1="" class="message-box-container" id="message-box-container">
        </div>
        <div _ngcontent-c1="" class="chat-input"><input _ngcontent-c1="" class="ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid">
          <button _ngcontent-c1="">Send</button>
        </div>
        <div _ngcontent-c1="" class="chat-detail">
          <p _ngcontent-c1="">User count: 1</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </app-chat>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I've tried that. This doesn't work for me unfortunately. I will post in Edit what happens when I do that.

Comment: @Nov This seems to answer the question but something else is at play perhaps...which the question does not contain.

Comment: If you check the last photo in my question. You'll notice there is additional content above the chat box. Changing the .chat-container to 82% fixed the problem. Along with using flex:1 0 auto for the message-box-container

Comment: But now the problem is the chat box dynamically expands, but it doesn't shrink when minimizing the screen